# Change color dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the colour of div after checking whether it is red or green.

I have tried this but is not working.

```
if ($(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(34,187,69)"|| $(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(255,0,51)") {
    var s = confirm("Are you sure you want to pushback?");
    if (s == true) {
    $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");  
   }
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The value returned by background color depends on browser... so a better solution is to check for some class if possible

Comment: I am setting the specific colour for div before and the have mentioned the rgb values of that color

Comment: there also seems to be something wrong with your code. you store the result of the `confirm` in `var s`, but after that you are checking for a variable named `r`

Comment: can you try to log the value like `console.log(this, $(this).css("background-color"))` to see what is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser returns the value as rgb(34, 187, 69). but you are comparing it as rgb(34,187,69). Thats the reason its not executing the inner statements.

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Color is different depend on browsers. So use class in css and check with jquery using `hasClass()`.

```
.green{
  background-color: green;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

if ($(this).hasClass("green") || $(this).hasClass("red")) {
    var s = confirm("Are you sure you want to pushback?");
    if (s == true) {
    $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wrap').click(function(){
  var color_ = $(this).css("background-color");
  var colorr = rgb2hex(color_);
  if (colorr=='#ff0000') {
    var s = confirm("Are you sure you want to pushback?");
    if (s == true) {
    $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");  
      }
   } 
  });
});
  
  var hexDigits = new Array
        ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"); 

//Function to convert hex format to a rgb color
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
 return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function hex(x) {
  return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
 }
```

```css
#wrap{
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 function changeColor(obj) {
    if ($(obj).css("background-color") == "rgb(34, 187, 69)" || $(obj).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 51)") {
        var s = confirm("Are you sure you want to pushback?");
        if (s == true) {
            $(obj).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        }
    }
}
```

on html:

```
<input type="button" id="But_Change" value="changeColor" style="background-color: rgb(34,187,69)" onclick="changeColor(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Browser returns different values for colours.
But still give this a try:

```
function componentToHex(c) {
var hex = c.toString(16);
return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

alert( rgbToHex(0, 51, 255) );
```

try to compare after this.